# Achieving File Server Redundancy

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi, failover, redundancy, file-server

We are in the process of moving all servers (or virtualising physicals) into a central datacenter connected via MPLS.

Currently we are fully redundant on most aspects - RDS Farms, SQL Clusters, multiple DCs, hardware failover for firewalls etc. The cluster itself is a 4-node ESX Cluster.

However, file servers are a notorious pain to achieve some form of redundancy should the virtual machine crash or fail for whatever reason. Naturally if we were using Hyper-V something like Scale-out File Server (SOFS) with Client Access Points (CAPS) would work, but VMWare leaves fewer options.

Is Distributed File System (DFS) really a robust enough method for file server redundancy and if so, what are peoples recommendations for its configuration? Or whatever strategies have people implemented to achieve this?

Comment: `Is DFS really a robust enough method for file server redundancy` - Yes it is.

Comment: What's wrong with using cluster services using a multi-writer-bit-enabled VMDK and then share that out with SMB 3.0 on Server 2016/19 - this will allow for full node failure and client recovery by W10 users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DFS answer you.

You can create advanced scenario with DFS and clustering too. Like seen [there](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2009/06/29/deploying-dfs-replication-on-a-windows-failover-cluster-part-ii.aspx)

> Configuring high availability for the DFS Replication service
>
> In this section, we take a look at the steps required for configuring
>   a highly available file server on this newly created failover cluster.
>   As a result of these steps, the DFS Replication service also gets
>   configured automatically for high availability. Thereafter, this
>   failover cluster can be added to a DFS replication group.

Kinda a diagramme of how it's in the final if you follow their steps.

[image]